# PhpMyAdmin missing Text_Plain_Preappend_getInfo() function

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

Today, I wanted to connect on my PMA panel to update a column of a database but found a weird message : It was saying that **mbstring extension was missing** although it was working fine until now. I looked a bit on Google and ended up installing new packages.

Then I faced lots of successive errors, Apache refusing to restart because of PHP5 and PHP7 in conflict, PMA that couldn't find mcrypt again, etc...

Now, things are working fine on Apache/2.4.7 and PHP7 **BUT** when I am trying to modify a column structure on PMA, it gives me this error :

> Error in processing request | Error code 500 | Message Internal Server Error

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
sudo service apache2 restart
```

as stated here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699774/internal-server-error-http-error-500-after-installing-phpmyadmin-on-a-certain) but the error is still here.

Maybe it is related to a bad configuration during package installations, as it prompts at a moment :

```
Setting up phpmyadmin (4:4.0.10-1) ...
Configuration file '/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
```

I chose to keep my version but maybe there was an important change. I can't manage to have this question again to select "Y" instead of "N".

Any idea how to fix my problem and/or to fix my configuration ?
I tried to look in my logs files /var/log/apache2/error.log, /var/log/mysql.err, /var/log/mysql/error.log but they are all empty. I am not sure where PMA errors are logged.

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT**
I finally found some logs but the error is beyond my skills. Looks like there is something broken with my PMA installation ?

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   Text_Plain_Preappend_getInfo() in
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/transformations.lib.php:153

Comment: Is there Apache2's `mod_security2` installed?

Comment: Hello @SpasSpasov ! I tried "sudo apt-get install mod_security2", it wasn't installed so I did it and restarted apache. Still, the error is still present on PMA.

Comment: @SpasSpasov I just found some logs, edited my post. Thanks for helping !

Comment: My thought was, if there was mod_security2 installed, maybe it could throws this error, but in most cases it generates 403 errors. Whatever if you have decided to use mod_security2 [OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set](http://modsecurity.org/crs/) will make it really useful.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to have a working installation of PhpMyAdmin by uninstalling the existing package and installing a "compatible version" from another ppa :

http://techfolkz.com/5/install-php-7-apache-2-mysql-56-phpmyadmin-45-on-ubuntu

```
Install Phpmyadmin

You should install php7 compatible version of phpmyadmin.Following commands are for installing phpmyadmin 4.5.3 on your server.You can check details here.

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vincent-c/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: I just found that your old phpMyAdmin version (4:4.0.10-1) doesn't support PHP 7. [Here](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) is the reference.